# How to build for multiple targets with webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I followed the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) and implemented something that looks like this:

```
...
const config = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};

const nodeConfig = merge(common, {
    ...config,
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.node.js',
    },
    target: 'node',
});

const webConfig = merge(common, {
    ...config,
    node: {
        crypto: true,
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.web.js',
    },
    target: 'web',
});

module.exports = [nodeConfig, webConfig];
```

However, only **one** target gets through and I don't think there's a deterministic process to figure out which one gets built (that is, sometimes the web target is built, other times the node target).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the configuration above, but I feel that there's some racing condition whereby one target gets built before the other, so the node process exits before building both targets. Is that the case? Here's my [common config](https://gist.github.com/PaulRBerg/9ea000d2f9b1a1aaa7b078db8c5038da).

The version of webpack I'm using is `4.30.0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I sorted it out. In my common config, I was using [clean-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin):

```js
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ...
]
```

Obviously, when building the second target, the clean plugin was erasing the first target.

Most of the times, you don't really need this plugin, especially if you're deploying from CI.

Comment: Thank you so much! The same happens if you use `output: { clean: true }`. Only use that in the first config!